# ASP.NET Web Form - TreeView Nodes are dislocated

Tags: asp.net, treeview, nodes

The last node in the `TreeView` (ASP) control is being displayed at a different location, though the hierarchical logic remains and I can collapse the node.

The TreeView is nested within a Panel, which is inside a `<div>`. I have made enough place for it to expand, and even maximized the `TreeView` size, but same issue. Now after some days of searching for help here, and because I'm new in Web designing. Also, there is no `Scrollbar` Property for the `TreeView`. 
I'm coding using .`NET 3.5`

CODE:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="Genographic._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #form1
        {
            height: 100%;
        }

        .bigDiv
        {
            width: 100%;
            height: 155px;
            background-color: red;
        }
        .imageDiv
        {
            width: 50%;
            height: 600px;
            background-color: white;
        }
        .labelDiv
        {
            width: 39%;
            height: 600px;
            background-color: control;
        }

        div > div
        {
            float: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="bigDiv">
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel_Menu" runat="server" BackColor="#336699" Width="100%" Height="155px">
            <center>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="..."
                    Font-Size="X-Large" ForeColor="White"></asp:Label>
            </center>
            <br>
        </asp:Panel>
        <div class="imageDiv">
            <asp:Image ID="Image_Map" runat="server" Height="600px" Width="600px" ForeColor="#CCCCFF" />
        </div>
        <div class="labelDiv">
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="582px" Width="640px" Style="display: inline-block;">
                <br>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Level:      "></asp:Label>
                <br>
                <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView_Level" runat="server" PopulateNodesFromClient="False"
                    ShowLines="True" Height="300px" Width="251px">
                    <SelectedNodeStyle ForeColor="#FF6600" />
                </asp:TreeView>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                <br>
                <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView_2" runat="server" ShowLines="True">
                    <SelectedNodeStyle ForeColor="#FF6600" />
                </asp:TreeView>
            </asp:Panel>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you inspected the resulting HTML? That would be my first step. If that doesn't help you solve it then maybe you can share your code and tell us which browser is exhibiting this behavior?

Comment: @DaniDev The TreeView does not tell any HTML expect some encrypted text. I experience the same behavior on another browser too. It definitely looks like it cannot fit its children nodes and expands wherever not but as i said there is enough room specified.

Comment: What happens when you take out Take out the:  ' Height="300px" ' property?

Comment: @DaniDev Same bro. I'm currently experimenting and will post again.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using `absolute` positioning.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #form1
        {
            height: 100%;
        }

        .bigDiv
        {
            width: 100%;
            height: 155px;
            background-color: red;
        }
        .imageDiv
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 180px;
            left: 510px;
            width: 600px;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: green;
        }
        .labelDiv
        {
            position:absolute;
            top: 180px;
            left: 5px;
            width: 500px;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: yellow;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="bigDiv" style="background-color: #3366CC">
        <center>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="..."
                Font-Size="X-Large" ForeColor="White"></asp:Label>
        </center>
        <br>
        <div class="imageDiv">
            <asp:Image ID="Image_Map" runat="server" ForeColor="#CCCCFF" />
        </div>
        <div class="labelDiv">
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Level:"></asp:Label>
            <br>
            <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView_Level" runat="server" PopulateNodesFromClient="False"
                ShowLines="True" Width="416px">
                <SelectedNodeStyle ForeColor="#FF6600" />
            </asp:TreeView>
            <br>
            <br>
            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="...:"></asp:Label>
            <br>
            <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView_H" runat="server" ShowLines="True">
                <SelectedNodeStyle ForeColor="#FF6600" />
            </asp:TreeView>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```